# @media запросы не работают в IE c % / vw / vh

Tags: html, html5, css3

```
#window.floors, #window.apartments { 
  @media (max-width: 140vh) {
   ...
  }
}
```

В ie 11 и ниже не пашет. В Safari, FF, Chrome (последних) все окей. Пробовал добавлять тип экрана `all, screen`, - тоже не спасло. Если заменить на пиксели, то все ок. Но нужны именно динамические единицы :)

Пример:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="window" class="apartment">
        <span>This is TEEEEXT!</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

**main.css**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#window {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

#window.apartment {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#window.apartment span {
    font-size: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 140vh) {
    #window.apartment span {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Соберите, пожалуйста, полный пример, на котором можно посмотреть работу вашего кода и протестировать работоспособность в IE.

Comment: @VenZell прошу и жалую

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого используется специальная библиотека - [viewport-units-buggyfill](https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill)

Просто подключите библиотеку в конце html страницы:

```
<script src="viewport-units-buggyfill.js"></script>
<script>
window.viewportUnitsBuggyfill.init(); // простое подключение
/*
var hacks = require('viewport-units-buggyfill.hacks');
require('viewport-units-buggyfill').init({
  hacks: hacks
});
*/
</script>
```

Comment: Т.е. это баг IE?

Comment: @Даниил, я бы сказал недоработка.